# Get parent interface of interface in Java

Tags: java, class, interface

I need to recurse through all the interfaces and super classes of a given object. This works fine when the parent is another class, but when an interface extends another interface I get a NullPointerException.

Here is an example:

```
public class Test {

    private interface Foo {

    }

    private interface Bar extends Foo {

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(Bar.class.getSuperclass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

This throws a NullPointerException instead of printing `Foo` as expected. Is there any way of getting the super class of an interface?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

> Bar.class.getInterfaces()

to get the interfaces implemented by Bar.

**Update**

Depending on your needs, you might want to look for an specific interface or class:

> Bar bar = ...

```
if (bar instanceof Foo) {
    System.out.println(true);
}

// Or
if (Foo.class.isInstance(bar)) {
    System.out.println(true);
}

// Or
if (Foo.class.isAssignableFrom(Bar.class)) {
    System.out.println(true);
}
```

Comment: +1. Even though the declaration says the interface "extends" the other interface, it is not a super-class. Interfaces can "extend" multiple interfaces.

Comment: That was it - thanks for that. The extend and implement keywords are such a mess - in generics you use extend to specify interfaces, and then interfaces extend one another, yet they behave like they implement one another.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously figured it out as soon as I posted this..

For anyone else wondering, the parent interface of an interface is returned by the `getInterfaces()` method. The following prints `Foo` as expected:

```
public class Test {

    private interface Foo {

    }

    private interface Bar extends Foo {

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(Bar.class.getInterfaces()[0].getSimpleName());
    }
}
```